# Concatenating JSON results to single column postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-json

So, at the moment I have two columns in a table, one of which containing a JSON document, like so:

```
        CID:
        2
        Name:
        {"first" : "bob","1" : "william", "2" : "archebuster", "last" : "smith"}
```

When I do a search on this column using:

```
  SELECT "CID", "Name"->>(json_object_keys("Name")) AS name FROM "Clients" WHERE 
  "Name"->>'first' LIKE 'bob' GROUP BY "CID";
```

I get:

```
  CID | name
--------------
  2   | bob
  2   | william
  2   | archebuster
  2   | smith
```

When really I want:

```
 CID | name
  2  | bob william archebuster smith
```

How would i go about doing this? I'm new to JSON in postgresql.
I've tried string_agg and it wouldn't work, presumably because i'm working in a json column, despite the fact '->>' should type set the result to string

**UPDATE:**

[image]

Comment: No sure try `array_agg("Name"->>(json_object_keys("Name"))) AS name`

Comment: For array agg I get "set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set".

For string agg I get "Error: string_agg(text) does not exist "

Comment: Insert those values in a temp table and use array_agg on that.

Comment: Not entirely sure how to do that tbh, been trying to convert the thing to an array but run into the same problem, where each row is {bob} {william} etc

Comment: go here http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to understand, if you include a set-returning function into the `SELECT` clause, you will create an implicit [`LATERAL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) [`CROSS JOIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN).

Your query in reality looks like this:

```
SELECT "CID", "Name"->>"key" AS name
FROM "Clients"
CROSS JOIN LATERAL json_object_keys("Name") AS "foo"("key")
WHERE "Name"->>'first' LIKE 'bob'
GROUP BY "CID", "Name"->>"key"
```

If you really want to do that, you can apply an aggregate function here (possibly `array_agg` or `string_agg`).

<kbd>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c214f/4)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Aggregate functions don't work on this though. It makes the database complain that a 'set-valued function call is called in context that cannot accept a set'

Comment: @user3512424 You're wrong, aggregate function will work on this translated example. i.e. `array_agg("Name"->>"key") AS names`. Your query makes a perfect example to not use set-returning functions in the `SELECT` clause, unless you're know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: I don't think I am. See the results in : http://imgur.com/8S4JAqq

Oh, one second, i udnerstand what you're saying now.. will try again